# Selecting part of contingency table in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

### Problem

I am working on a project which is trying to detect the association of sexism and genders existent in the dataset. Part of the dataset looks like

```
    male  female  sexism?
0      0       1        1
1      1       1        0
2      0       1        1
3      1       1        1
4      1       1        0
..   ...     ...      ...
```

Now I would like to get the statistics of this dataset, which looks like

```
       sexism   non-sexism
male   xxx      xxx
female xxx      xxx
```

As much as I know I could do something similar to this using `pd.crosstab` (see following code chunk), but it is not as straightforward as I anticipated

```
pd.crosstab([[df["male"], df["sexism?"]], [[df["female"], df["sexism?"]])
```

Could someone help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you want to do , you have 4 D for male and female , and you only want two D ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need mean to see the percentage

```
df.groupby('sexism?').mean().T
Out[19]: 
sexism?    0         1
male     1.0  0.333333
female   1.0  1.000000
```

Update

```
df.groupby('sexism?').sum().T
Out[9]: 
sexism?  0  1
male     2  1
female   2  3
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But what if what I want is the **number** (instead of percentage) of each `xxx`. Say the `xxx` at the intersection of `male` and `sexism` means number of rows when `male=1` and `sexism?=1` while `xxx` at `male` and `non-sexism` means `male=1` and `sexism?=0`